# How to create a utility class that has common helpers?

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a utility class with common functions I need.  So they have to be static, and not leak memory.

Say I wanted to add this function that converts a NSString to a NSNumber:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"42"];
[f release];
```

How could I return the result, and not leak?

Would i have to use autorelease for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *autorelease* to avoid memory leaks when returning objects with uncertain ownership. `NSNumber`'s `numberFromString:` method returns an autoreleased value already, so you do not need to do anything special in your case. With objects of other classes, you can do this:

```
MyClass *ret = [[[MyClass alloc] initWithSomeValue:42] autorelease];
```

Note that if you use ARC you do not need to do any of this: the compiler is smart enough to figure most of it out for you.

In Objective C static methods of Java/C++/C# are called *class methods*. You denote them with a `+` instead of `-` in the declaration, and remember that you cannot access instance methods from the implementation.

In the header:

```
@interface MyHelper : NSObject
+(NSString*)format:(NSNumber*)num;
@end
```

In the implementation:

```
@implementation MyHelper

+(NSString*)format:(NSNumber*)num {
    return [num stringValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you show me how to setup a utility class that has static methods?